# Add an XFCE-style directory menu to Windows 7/8.1

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, xfce

XFCE has the [directory menu](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/directorymenu). Setting the file pattern to * gives you one-click access to a menu with all the [files and folders](http://i62.tinypic.com/5cmv76.png) under a given directory on your hard drive. Is there a way to get this for Windows 7 and/or 8.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom Toolbar.

- Right-click the taskbar.
- Click Toolbars >
- Click New Toolbar...
- You will get a "New Toolbar" window
- Browse to the folder that you would like to have quick access to
- Click "OK"

There is no option to filter contents using patterns, but for your original question where you mention "*" wildcard, this will do just fine.